# Binding a <h:inputText> value to a bean property while showing a different text into the field

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, facelets

I know that the title may sound absurd, but I don't know ho to explain what I mean :)

I've got a form that I use to edit an entity.
Each field is linked to its related bean property and it works fine.

What I need to do is to show the current values of the entity in the form fields, in order to make editing a bit faster (having the current value instead of an empty field is quite useful!)

So I've got this edit.xhtml page, that takes the ID from a get parameter and retrieves the entity using a getFromId method in the backing bean.

Assuming that this entity is stored into a var called "contact", I'd like to have this form :

```
<f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="Edit"/></h1>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contactsMB.name}" title="Name" required="true"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Surname:" for="surname" />
                <h:inputText id="surname" value="#{contactsMB.surname}" title="Cognome"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Email:" for="email" />
                <h:inputText id="email" value="#{contactsMB.email}" title="Email" required="true"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Number:" for="number" />
                <h:inputText id="number" value="#{contactsMB.number}" title="Number" />
                <h:inputHidden id="id" value="#{contactsMB.id}"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{contactsMB.editContact}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
```

but I want to show into the texfields the values of the contact var.

So, for example, the first inputText must show "stefano" as name but it has to be linked to contactsMB.name.

Basically it's just like a default value for the inputText, and this default value must come from an entity.

Is that possible?

Comment: How do exactly your requirements differ from the default behaviour of JSF inputs which show bound value?

Comment: I knew that was hard to explain my problem so I'm trying again.
If I use <h:inputText value="#{contactsMB.name}"/>, it shows the value given by contactsMB.getName() and it calls contactsMB.setName() when I send the form.
But I need to show the value given by contact.name, where contact is a var that refers to an entity's instance, and not the value from contactsMB.name !
So it has to show a value that's NOT the one taken from the beans' property, while still setting the beans' property when the form is submitted.

Comment: Can't you just put your "default" values into contactsMB?

Comment: I see. I still don't get the whole picture though :) Why can't you populate contactsMB with values from contact initially? You need to detect the explicit edits somehow?

Comment: No, because they're not really default values.
Those values depends on the ID parameter passed to the page, they're not "fixed" values!
I need something like 
<h:inputText value="#{contactsMB.name}" defaultText=#{contact.name]"/>
where contact is
<c:set var="contact" value="#{contactsMB.getFromId(request.getParameter('id'))}"/>
so the input text shows the value from contact.name, but it "writes" to contactsMB.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should ask yourself: `Do you really need to do that?`. If you are editing an Entity, you should directly take advantage of the getters an setters of that Entity. It may be something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public void ContactsMB {

   @EJB
   private SomeEJB someEJB;
   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.username}")
   private String username;
   private User   user;

   @PostConstruct
   public void prepareEditing() {
      this.user = someEJB.loadUserFromDatabase(username);
   }

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

Then you can, for example, display the user's name like this:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{contactsMB.user.name}" />
```

The above `<h:inputText>` will display the user's current name as default value. When you type in a new name and submit, the `User` Entity will be updated directly.

If you really want to do it as you explained, you can change the `@PostConstruct` method to be like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public void ContactsMB {

   @EJB
   private SomeEJB someEJB;
   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.username}")
   private String username;
   private User   user;

   private String name;
   private String email;

   @PostConstruct
   public void prepareEditing() {
      this.user  = someEJB.loadUserFromDatabase(username);
      this.name  = user.getName();
      this.email = user.getEmail();
   }

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: @ManagedProperty(value = "#{request.getParameter('id')}")
protected String id;
This one worked, even if our teacher did not explain this annotation!
Really thanks :)

Comment: If you are using `@ManagedProperty`, you should use JSF's `param` instead of `#{request.getParameter('id')}`. I think you should change it to `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")`.